# C# panel low quality printing

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

I know this has been asked before, but I can't get a straight answer. I understand that my monitor's resolution is lower to that of my printer, but anyway. I have a panel that contains labels and a picturebox. When I print it on paper, it has de quality of a screen capture. I can't find a way to get a decent print. Here's my code:

In my contructor:

```
printdoc1.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(printdoc1_PrintPage);
printdoc1.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("", 275, 850);
```

event handers and methods

```
public void GetPrintArea(Panel pnl)
    {
        MemoryImage = new Bitmap(pnl.Width, pnl.Height);
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, pnl.Width, pnl.Height);
        pnl.DrawToBitmap(MemoryImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, pnl.Width, pnl.Height));

    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MemoryImage != null)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(MemoryImage, 0,0);
            base.OnPaint(e);     
        }
    }
   void printdoc1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle pagearea = e.PageBounds;
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(MemoryImage, 0,0);          
    }
```

And finally, whats inside of my print button:

```
GetPrintArea(panelImpresion);
previewdlg.Document = printdoc1;
previewdlg.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: where do you set the dpi for the printing Graphics object?

Comment: @TaW I haven't. Could that be the problem? I know its not the best idea to print a windows form, but I'm algo printing a chart.

Comment: Go ahead and try.. The default is 96dpi or, to be precise: your screen's dpi. See here for [Chart printing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456718%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)!